# Array filtering and object conversion: what is fastest and what other considerations matter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Say I need to transform an array into an object, and do some filtering in the process.

I have two approaches, one with chainable functional methods such as `.map`, `.filter` and `.reduce`, and one that loops over the array with an old school `for-loop` and mutates an object.

**Functional way:**

```
const output = fields
    .filter(field => field.required)
    .map(field => field.name)
    .reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
      acc[cur] = false;
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

**Old school `for-loop` way:**

```
let output2 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  if (fields[i].required) {
    output2[fields[i].name] = false;
  }
}
```

I prefer the functional approach as I think it leads to better readable code. I was surprised (and slightly disappointed) to learn however that the functional approach is consistently slower than the non-functional, old school `for-loop` way of transforming. Please find [the JSBench here](http://jsben.ch/WfYfT).

I figure a couple of things could be the matter here:

1. I am an idiot and my implementations are flawed and can be optimized.
2. "JSBench is not the best way to measure performance. Tool X, Y, Z is a much better way to measure performance"
3. "The performance penalty with the functional approach is worth it because you can use `const` which has other beneficial aspects such as (semi-) immutability."

Anyone care to weigh in?

You can find the test array I'm using in the JSBench link.

Comment: No, a few functions to be called repeatedly will never beat a for loop. Notw that youll iterate 3 times with the first one vs. once with the second. I think lodash chains are able to write the first, but actually do the second ( not quite shure)

Comment: @Jonasw Well, actually... http://jsben.ch/ANYb1 it seems the functional approach can be even faster

Comment: Indeed. I notices something slightly weird though: the JSBench with 3 approaches gives much better results to the optimized functional implementation than a JSBench with just the optimized functional and for-loop approaches. Three implementations: http://jsben.ch/ANYb1 Two implementations: http://jsben.ch/fPcwS

Comment: @pablo theres probably some good inlining going on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "filter map reduce"  loops 3 times the same array.
So one for  loop is always faster.
But reduce on its own works fine

```
    const output = fields
    .reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
      if(cur.required){
        acc[cur.name] = false;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Indeed as I suspected, I am an idiot. Of course, this is a much better way. According to JSBench this implementation is very very close to the `for-loop` approach: 100% versus 99% and ekes out a win in most runs.

Answer (score 1):

Another functional way, probably up to three times faster:

```
const output = fields
.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(curr.required) acc[cur.name] = false;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

And you may also use a Map ( better performance later):

```
const output=new Map(fields.map(el=>el.required?[el.name,false]:[0,false]));
output.delete(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in combination with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
const output = Object.assign({}, ...fields.map(o => (o.required && { [o.name]: false })));
```

Comment: I like this approach, very clean. But in a one on one with the `for-loop` the `for-loop` wins: http://jsben.ch/T5x7X

Comment: just an idea to give you some more possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated @nina :)